# Adding a new input field within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

http://jsfiddle.net/yhv9bjrx/2/

In the fiddle above, I'm trying to let users add a new open time when they hit the new item button. The problem I'm having is that when the button is clicked, it updates both events in the ng-repeat, instead of the current event its on.

```
<ul>
      <li ng-repeat="event in orgEvents">
          <h3>Event ID: {{event.CampaignEventID}}</h3>
          <h2>Event Name: {{event.Name}}</h2>          
          <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="time in orgEventTimes">
              <div ng-if="time.CampaignEventID == 1">
                  Event ID: <input type="text" ng-model="time.CampaignEventID">
                  Open:  <input type="text" ng-model="time.OpenTime">
              </div>
          </li>
           <button ng-click="add(item)">New Item</button>

          </ul>
          <hr/>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Also for some reason the ng-if statement is not working, and it is showing every event in the $scope.orgEventTimes array, instead of just the ones belong to this event.

Comment: Are you bound to use the same data structure of events and it't time i.e. events in a separate list and their times in a separate list, or can you change the data structure?

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal unfortunately I'm bound to the same data structure of them both being in separate lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/3aqwng8o/

I don't know why the `ng-if` isn't working.. 
Instead of using `ng-if` why not use a `filter`?

`<li ng-repeat="time in orgEventTimes|filter: {CampaignEventID:event.CampaignEventID}">`

Your button to add an item is simply pushing an empty object into the orgEventTimes array. Have it push an object that includes the CampaignEventID of the event for that instance of `ng-repeat` loop.

```
   $scope.add = function (item) {
          $scope.orgEventTimes.push(item);
        };
```

`<button ng-click="add({CampaignEventID: event.CampaignEventID})">New Item</button>`

Comment: I wouldn't expose the CampaignEventID as an input either as the input will disappear if you delete it, but still remain in the array with a blank ID, but presumably this was just for testing/development purposes.